# Rest API with authentication

Tags: json, rest, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Apache Zeppelin 0.70 REST API, and I'm trying to run a pagraph via a POST request.

When I authenticate via /api/login , I get this response:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "message": "",
  "body": {
    "principal": "nifi",
    "ticket": "5d7e892a-e3cc-489f-ba97-ad7aeecad6e5",
    "roles": "[admin]"
  }
}
```

then I want to run my notebook paragraph via post request api/notebook/job/2CAYTKD7M/20170228-185210_117285001 , but I get this error like I'm not authenticated :

```
<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> <title>Error 500 Server Error</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2> <p>Problem accessing /api/login;JSESSIONID=3144aa0c-3c31-49a0-864f-9ac14295bee7. Reason: <pre>
```

How can I include my token , ticket so I can use it in my post request? Or any idea how to fix it in any other way?

Comment: But where I can find this token ? is it the ticket id ?

Comment: All websockets communications require the username and ticket to be submitted by the browser. Upon receiving a websocket message, the server checks that the ticket received is the one assigned to the username through the HTTP request (step 3 above).
 take a look here https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/SECURITY-README.md

Comment: look at this commit too https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/53/commits/c2b3cf325244ddf52e46723190d191cb93824900
How the api is called `@Path("interpreter/bind/{noteId}/{principal}/{ticket}")`